# Javascript, Ajax and Alert Not Working

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I'm new to Javascript and Ajax, and trying to figure out why my code below isn't working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cadlib').bind('click', function () {
      $.get("/models/"+this.id+"/viewmodelinfo/", function(data) {
        alert ("yo");  // This line bellow doesn't execute
        if (data.fact_type=="T") {
          guess_result="This fact is true! " + data.fact_note;
        } else {
          alert ("yo");
          guess_result="This fact is false! " + data.fact_note;
        }
        $('#result').replaceWith("guess_result");
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

Here's my HTML

```
<a href = "#mySymbolModal" class = "cadlib" id = "{{symbol.id}}" data-toggle="modal" style = "text-align:center; color: #FF761A;" href="/models/{{symbol.id}}/view_model/"><span id = "modelname"> {{symbol.modelname.upper}}</span> - <span id = "format">{{ symbol.format }}</span><span id = "adder" style="visibility:hidden;">{{symbol.adder}}</span><span id = "adderid" style="visibility:hidden;"> {{symbol.adder.id}}</span><span id = "symbolobject" style="visibility:hidden;">{{symbol}}</span></a>
```

I think there is something wrong with the commented line. My alert is not instantiating.

Is there something I'm missing that would cause the alert to not work?

Comment: [As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#bind-events)

Comment: is there any error in the console

Comment: is the first `alert` displayed

Comment: Yes, it says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny No, neither alert is displayed.

Comment: Try opening the dynamically built url (ie. `"/models/" + this.id + "/viewmodelinfo/"`) in your browser and see if it works.

Comment: Yes I did and it works...

Comment: I also tried hardcoding the url.

Comment: `$.get("/models/"+this.id+"/viewmodelinfo/", function(data) {` this line is the problem, it's the `this.id`. Can you post also the one line code that you click to trigger this function

Comment: Ok I added the code that triggers the function.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess its the 'this.id', try using on alert(this.id) before the $.get to see what its producing (or not).

I do something similar which should give you the idea

```
$(".productpicturedelete").on("click", "input[type=button]", function(event){
        var $buttonid = $(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: I don't think that's it because it is giving the right path when I do an alert on it.

Comment: What about adding the .done(), .fail() and .always() to try and trap better what's going off?

Answer (score 0):

Data source file name is missing in URL field:

$.get("/models/"+this.id+"/viewmodelinfo/<data source file name>", function(data) {..});

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.cadlib').bind('click', function () {
            data_id = $(this).attr('id'); //add this

            $.get("/models/" + data_id + "/viewmodelinfo/", function(data) {
                alert ("yo");  // This line bellow doesn't execute
                if (data.fact_type=="T") {
                    guess_result="This fact is true! " + data.fact_note;
                } else {
                    alert ("yo");
                    guess_result="This fact is false! " + data.fact_note;
                }
                $('#result').replaceWith("guess_result");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am almost sure that this.id doesn't exists in this context

```
$.get("/models/"+this.id+"/viewmodelinfo/", function(data)
```

What does this.id suppouse to be? Can you explain it please